# `map` and `filter` in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having the following input:

```
var m = [{
    name: 'foo',
    routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/foo1'},
      {verb: 'get', path: '/foo2'}]
  }, {
    name: 'bar',
    routes: [{verb: 'put', path: '/:id'}]},
  {
    name: '__ignoreme',
    routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/baz1'},
      {verb: 'get', path: '/baz2'}]
  }]
```

Using `map` and `filter` I want to achieve:

```
  var desired = [
  'foo POST /foo1',
  'foo GET /foo2',
  'bar PUT /:id',
]
```

Complete code:

```
    var m = [{
        name: 'foo',
        routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/foo1'},
          {verb: 'get', path: '/foo2'}]
      }, {
        name: 'bar',
        routes: [{verb: 'put', path: '/:id'}]},
      {
        name: '__ignoreme',
        routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/baz1'},
          {verb: 'get', path: '/baz2'}]
      }]



    var desired = [
      'foo POST /foo1',
      'foo GET /foo2',
      'bar PUT /:id',
    ]


    var myOutput = m
            .filter(function (m) {
              return m.name.indexOf('__') === -1;
            })
            .map(function (m) {
              return [
                m.name,
                m.routes[0].verb.toUpperCase(),    // I should loop through my array instead of getting just the first element
// But can I loop through the array in my map?        
                m.routes[0].path
              ].join(' ');
            });


    console.log('>myOutput:', myOutput);
    // What I achieve which is not desired : 
    // [
    // 'foo POST /foo1',
    //  'foo PUT /:id',
    //]
```

This is the structure which is is used in my code and I want to achieve my desired output with the small change and still using `map` and `filter`.

Comment: yea is there any way to loop into my array?

Comment: I don't understand, you are expecting `'foo GET /foo2'` in your output? But you've explicitly filtered it out.

Comment: yes how can I loop into my array of routes inside my `map` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop inside of the map function to ensure you look at all routes for a given name.  That will return an array of arrays, so I used reduce after the map to flatten that into a single array of strings.

```
var myOutput = m
        .filter(function (m) {
          return m.name.indexOf('__') === -1;
        })
        .map(function (m) {
          var arr = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < m.routes.length; i++){
            arr.push([
              m.name,
              m.routes[i].verb.toUpperCase(),            
              m.routes[i].path
            ].join(' '));
          }
          return arr;
        }).reduce(function(prev, cur){
          return prev.concat(cur);
        });
```

This results in myOutput of `["foo POST /foo1", "foo GET /foo2", "bar PUT /:id"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your `routes` array  as well within every item and map the values to get the `verb` and `path`

```js
 var m = [{
        name: 'foo',
        routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/foo1'},
          {verb: 'get', path: '/foo2'}]
      }, {
        name: 'bar',
        routes: [{verb: 'put', path: '/:id'}]},
      {
        name: '__ignoreme',
        routes: [{verb: 'post', path: '/baz1'},
          {verb: 'get', path: '/baz2'}]
      }]



    var desired = [
      'foo POST /foo1',
      'foo GET /foo2',
      'bar PUT /:id',
    ]


    var myOutput = m
            .filter(function (a) {
              return a.name.indexOf('__') === -1;
            })
            .map(function (a) {
              return a.routes.map(function (item) {
                return [
                  a.name,
                  item.verb.toUpperCase(),  
                  item.path
                ].join(' ');
              });
            })
            .reduce(function(prev, current){
              return prev.concat(current);
            })


    document.write('>myOutput:', myOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

After filtering your input, you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each set of routes into the desired format, then use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to join these arrays together:

```js
var m = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'post', path: '/foo1'},
            {verb: 'get', path: '/foo2'}]
    },{
        name: 'bar',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'put', path: '/:id'}]
    },{
        name: '__ignoreme',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'post', path: '/baz1'},
            {verb: 'get', path: '/baz2'}]
    }
];

var filter = function(a){
    return a.filter(function(x){
        return x.name !== '__ignoreme';
    });
};

var format = function(name, route){
    return name + ' ' + route.verb.toUpperCase() + ' ' + route.path;
};

var process = function(a){
    if(!a.length){
        return [];
    }
    return a[0].routes.map(function(r){
        return format(a[0].name, r);
    }).concat(process(a.slice(1)));
}

console.log(process(filter(m)));
```

**ES6 version**

```js
const m = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'post', path: '/foo1'},
            {verb: 'get', path: '/foo2'}]
    },{
        name: 'bar',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'put', path: '/:id'}]
    },{
        name: '__ignoreme',
        routes: [
            {verb: 'post', path: '/baz1'},
            {verb: 'get', path: '/baz2'}]
    }
];

const filter = xs => xs.filter(x => x.name !== '__ignoreme');
const format = (name, route) => `${name} ${route.verb.toUpperCase()} ${route.path}`;
const process = ([x,...xs]) =>
    x === undefined ? [] : [...x.routes.map(r => format(x.name,r)), ...process(xs)];

console.log(process(filter(m)));
```

**ES6 references:**
[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const),
[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) parameters,
[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and
[spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).